# how to correctly use ViewModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I created a simple application where I have a product list and search filter sidebar.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXwss.png)
I had a problem with pagination(using `PagedList`) because after filtering results and moving on next page(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qSnA.png) I was getting an empty page. Reason was clear. I was getting data in controller action parameters, so after clicking next page button, filter data was lost. So I decided to store this data somewhere.

I was told that I needed ViewModel, so I created another model `FilterModel` with side bar fields:

```
public class FilterModel {
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? MinPrice { get; set; }
    public int? MaxPrice { get; set; }
}
```

and this is `Products` model

```
public partial class Products {
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ......
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

And put them in `ViewModel`:

```
public class HomeViewModel {
    public IPagedList<Products> Repository { get; set; }
    public FilterModel FilterView { get; set; }
}
```

these are my controllers - `HomeController` that displays every product and `SearchFilterController` that should display filtered products:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    IProductRepository _repository;
    public HomeController(IProductRepository rep) {
        _repository = rep;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int page=1) {
        ViewBag.Manufacturers = Manufacturers.ManufacturersList(_repository);
        var model =
            (from p in _repository.Product
             orderby p.Price descending
             select p).ToPagedList(page, 2);
        ViewBag.Title = "Home";
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class SearchFilterController : Controller {
        IProductRepository _repository;
        public SearchFilterController(IProductRepository rep) {
            _repository = rep;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Filter(FilterModel filterModel, int page = 1) {
            ViewBag.Manufacturers = Manufacturers.ManufacturersList(_repository);
            var model =
                (from p in _repository.Product
                 where (p.Manufacturer == filterModel.Manufacturer || p.Name.Contains(filterModel.Name) || 
                    p.Price >= filterModel.MinPrice || p.Price <= filterModel.MaxPrice)
                 orderby p.Price descending
                 select p).ToPagedList(page, 1);
            ViewBag.Title = "Results";
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

In both controllers I pass `views` `PagedList<Products>` model but they should be getting `HomeViewModel` I guess.

these are my views:
`Index`(`HomeController`)

```
@model SmartPhoneCatalog.Models.HomeViewModel
@using System.Linq
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc
@using SmartPhoneCatalog.Domain.Abstract

...

<div id="root">
     @Html.Partial("_Sidebar", Model)

     @Html.Partial("_ProductsList", Model)
</div>

<br>
<div class="pagedList" data-sc-target="#products">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Repository, page => Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { page }),
                PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast);
</div>
```

`Filter`(`SearchFilterController`)

```
@model SmartPhoneCatalog.Models.HomeViewModel
@using System.Linq
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc
@using SmartPhoneCatalog.Domain.Abstract

...

<div id="root">
    @Html.Partial("_Sidebar", Model)

    @Html.Partial("_ProductsList", Model)
</div>

<br>
<div class="pagedList" data-sc-target="#products">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.FilterModel, page => Url.Action("Filter", "SearchFilter", new { page }),
                PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast);
</div>
```

Partial View:
`_Sidebar`

```
@model SmartPhoneCatalog.Models.HomeViewModel
@using System.Linq
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc

    <div id="filter" class="left">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "SearchFilter")) {
            <div>
                <b>Manufacturer:</b> <br>
                <select name="manufacturer" class="form-control">
                    <option>@null</option>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Manufacturers) {
                        <option>@item</option>
                    }
                </select><br>

                <b>Name:</b> <br>@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.FilterModel.Name)<br>
                <b>Price From:</b> <br>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FilterModel.Name)<br>
                <b>To:</b> <br>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FilterModel.Name)<br>
                <button type="submit" value="search"><b>Search</b></button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

I think I have everything done right in views. but I don't know how to pass them models correclty and   object binding is done right or not.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** OK, I did this in Controllers: Created `HomeViewModel` object and changed this

```
var model =
            (from p in _repository.Product
             orderby p.Price descending
             select p).ToPagedList(page, 2);
return View(model);
```

into this:

```
_homeView.Repository =
            (from p in _repository.Product
             orderby p.Price descending
             select p).ToPagedList(page, 2);
return View(_homeView);
```

now everything works except the pagination after filtering results(what was the reason why I did all of this :D). So I have to fix model binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi I have executed your code.. below are the changes

> Declare a Model like this

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? MinPrice { get; set; }
    public int? MaxPrice { get; set; }
}

public partial class Products
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<Products> Repository { get; set; }
    public FilterModel FilterView { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller(s) action methods are

```
 public class PagingController : Controller
{
    int pagesize = 2;

    public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
    {
        HomeViewModel _HomeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

        //call service and get products list
        AgentServiceReference.AgentServiceClient ServiceClient = new AgentServiceClient();
        var productlist = ServiceClient.GetProducts().ToPagedList(page, pagesize);

        //set IPagedList<Products> to our HomeViewModel Repository property
        _HomeViewModel.Repository = productlist;

        // set view bag  this we use for Drop Down list
        SetViewBags();
        ViewBag.Title = "Home";
        return View(_HomeViewModel);
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Filter(int page = 1)
    {
        //call service and get products list
        AgentServiceReference.AgentServiceClient ServiceClient = new AgentServiceClient();
        var productlist = ServiceClient.GetProducts().ToPagedList(page, pagesize);

        //set IPagedList<Products> to our HomeViewModel Repository property
        HomeViewModel _homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
        _homeViewModel.Repository = productlist;
        SetViewBags();
        return View("Index", _homeViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(HomeViewModel HomeViewModel)
    {
        HomeViewModel _homeviewModel = new HomeViewModel();
        AgentServiceReference.AgentServiceClient ServiceClient = new AgentServiceClient();

        var productlist = ServiceClient.GetProducts();
        // do filter stuff here........
        var resultpagedList = productlist.ToPagedList(3, pagesize);

        _homeviewModel.Repository = resultpagedList;

        SetViewBags();
        return View("Index", _homeviewModel);
    }

    private void SetViewBags()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> manufactures = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            manufactures.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Text" + i, Value = "Value" + i, Selected = false });

        }
        ViewBag.Manufacturers = manufactures;
    }
}
```

> Index.cshtml page

```
@using System.Linq
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model EntityLayer.HomeViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Paging", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div id="root">
    @Html.Partial("_Sidebar", Model)
    @Html.Partial("_ProductsList", Model)
</div>
}
```

> _Sidebar.cshtml

```
@model EntityLayer.HomeViewModel
@using System.Linq
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc
<div id="filter" class="left">
<div>
    <b>Manufacturer:</b>
    <br>        
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FilterView.Manufacturer, ViewBag.Manufacturers as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
    <b>Name:</b>
    <br>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FilterView.Name)<br>
    <b>Price From:</b>
    <br>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FilterView.MaxPrice)<br>
    <b>To:</b>
    <br>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FilterView.MinPrice)<br>
    <button type="submit" value="search"><b>Search</b></button>
</div>
```

> and finally _ProductsList.cshtml

```
@model EntityLayer.HomeViewModel
@using System.Linq
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Repository)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Price</td>
    </tr>
}
```

```
<div class="pagedList" data-sc-target="#products">
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Repository, page => Url.Action("Filter", "Paging", new { page }),
            PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast);
```

- Change the name spaces of EntityLayer.HomeViewModel accordingly
- The Approach you followed may not be correct since we are passing entire HomeViewModel every time where a partial view indeed needs specific model.
- it would be better if you achecive the same using ajax request
  Please note I didn't apply layout as you have provided images.
  Result images are
  [image: On Load]
  [image: First Paging]
  [image: Given Model Values]
  [image: Model Binding When Post]

Hope it helps you

Comment: Wow. thanks for your answer. I'll check and and reply if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @misho let me know if you are facing any problem. Mark it as answer  if it helps you :)